# Formatting 1TB External Drive - Mac/PC

Tags: windows, macos, external-hard-drive, filesystems

We have 1 mac user in a PC environment... and I have bought a 1TB WD external hard drive and need to format it so that both PC and Mac can read/write to it. Doing this from the mac should be easy, but I do not know where to format the drive from, and what is the best option to format it to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Beside Paragons NTFS offering, there is also [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/), which implements NTFS as a FUSE (File System in User Space) driver and is free.

As long as you control all systems that need to read/write the disk and can make sure they have an NTFS driver installed (every MacOS since at least 10.4 can read but not write NTFS) , I would recommend going with NTFS as this is a much more stable and secure FS. FAT was never meant to be used on TB size FS sizes.

Comment: +1 about sizes. FAT32 is limited to 2TB volume size, and 4GB file size.

Comment: I'm using NTFS + NTFS-3G on osx with a 250GB external HDD and it's very slow on reading/caching and especially writing. Any tips to get decent speeds with NTFS-3G please ?

Answer (score 3):

Use Disk Utility under /Applications/Utility. Select the device or existing volume on the left and select the 'Erase' tab. Choose the 'MS-DOS (FAT)' format.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the disk on both a Mac and "PC" then your best bet is to use FAT32. Most disks should already come formatted as such, but you can easily format it on a Windows machine if you need to. If you want to format it from the Mac, use Disk Utility from the `/Applications/Utilities` directory.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, you can use FAT but if you prefer to use NTFS the MAC will need a suitable driver, such as the one from [Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/). I notice it's currently selling for about half price.