# Which harddrive format do I use for both Mac and Windows to write/read?

Tags: windows, macos, external-hard-drive, filesystems

Is there a format for a hard drive that both Mac and Windows OS can read/write to?

I want an external hard drive that stores files they can both read/write, and use for backups, etc.

Comment: this question has been asked several times before.  see http://superuser.com/questions/47257/formatting-1tb-external-drive-mac-pc or http://superuser.com/questions/72546/external-hard-drive-how-to-format-it or... (can anyone else find a better "duplicate"?)

Answer (score 1):

[FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) is the best option since it works with all OSes. [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) has drivers available, so you should also be able to use it with Linux, Mac and Windows. [HFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System) would be a poor choice. FAT32 cannot handle files greater than 4 GB though.

Answer (score 0):

[FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) is the most supported, but its biggest flaw is that it doesn't support large files (> ~4 GiB). Next would probably be [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), supported (albeit not perfectly) on Mac by default (I think). Next would be [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus), the native file system for Mac OS, but not technically supported on Windows by default. (Unless you call playing with mounting, drivers, and such "defaults").

In short, go with FAT32 if all files < 4 GB, otherwise NTFS.